# No Endor wildfires?

Tags: star-wars

As everyone knows, there was [no Endor holocaust](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoEndorHolocaust) when the Death Star exploded, even though there probably should have been one.  But I've got to wonder about the events immediately prior.

Endor is referred to in *Return of the Jedi* as a "forest moon," implying that a significant fraction [(if not all)](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SingleBiomePlanet) of its land surface is covered in the sort of heavy forests we see in the scenes set on Endor.  Well, for an hour or so prior to the destruction of the second Death Star, there was a fairly heavy firefight going on in the forest.  Bolts of superheated plasma were fired all over, both from blasters and also much heavier machine-mounted weapons, and most of them, fired with typical Stormtrooper accuracy, missed their target and hit some piece of the scenery instead.  Speeders and walkers ended up exploding all over the place, and at the very end, a fortified military installation was razed with high explosives, setting off a massive explosion that could be seen for miles around.

And yet, in the celebration scene at the end, we see no evidence of the horrific  conflagrations that should have swept through the entire region and devastated the Ewoks' home forest.  Does any canonical explanation exist for how this battle never managed to touch off a massive wildfire?

Comment: Stormtrooper aim is so bad, **they missed the forest**.

Comment: @Oldcat: That might make sense if they had actually been aiming for the forest...

Comment: just looking at endor leads me to believe its a very "wet" planet. were i live in the midwest there are almost never forest fires because forests here are super wet and moist all the time, i could litterally toss gasoline on a tree in the closest forest to me, and once the gas burrned off the tree would stop burning their so wet. this is in contrast to the forests by California, which are very dry forests and will in fact start on fire easily. This is most likely the reason their were no fires, however, i dont actually know if endor is a wet forest, while i believe it is.

Comment: Aside from that, alien trees that tall might also be fire resistant or have a higher ignition point.

Comment: Even so, blowing up a reactor strong enough to project a force field into space that could shield something as big as the Death Star from attack by heavy cruisers should have released energy in magnitudes usually reserved to describe nuclear blasts.  Wildfires are a known consequence of such large releases.  (See the Tunguska event, which took place in a "wet" area, for one example.)

Comment: actually blowing up something like a nuclear reactor wouldn't even be the equivalent of a nuclear bomb, the explosion would be the size of whatever device was used to blow it up in the first place. you have to have the material in a very specific state, and blow it up in a very specific way for a nuclear sized explosion. this is even true for nuclear warheads as well. an outside explosion is not likely to have an actual nuclear reaction type explosion. So blowing up the shield generator reactor most likely will not result in an extra big explosion.

Comment: "**Can a nuclear power plant explode like an atom bomb?**
Absolutely not. A nuclear explosion is impossible in a commercial nuclear power plant. A power plant doesn’t contain the type of fuel in the amount which is needed to make atomic bombs." https://www.nh.gov/safety/divisions/hsem/nuclearpowerplants/npfaqseabrook.html  we can assume that the people with far more advanced tech have similar features.

Comment: I don't know if I should make this an official answer, but the scenes were shot in the Pacific Northwest, which, as I understand it, is technically a rainforest (or something close to it).  The trees on Endor are similar to Redwoods, which tend to grow in very wet environments.  The forest was probably quite damp, and the bark of redwood trees is very thick and tough, so the forest was probably just fine.  If you've ever seen a survival show set in a similar location, you know that the survivalists always have trouble trying to get a fire started.

Comment: @Himarm - there isn't really one type of forest in California.  Most of the big wildfires are in scrubland like Malibu.  The redwood forests are quite different, much more humid and damp, etc. And as a matter of fact, the Endor scenes were filmed in redwood forests in the Pacific Northwest, which are indeed very damp.  I think they're actually considered to be rainforests.  Everything in those forests is soaking wet most of the time.  And redwoods are actually pretty resistant to wildfires, because the foliage is so far above the ground.  The bark gets scorched, but the trees don't catch fire

Comment: @Himarm: Modern nuclear reactors only have to produce enough power to run a city or two.  This reactor had to produce enough power to project a space-battle-scale defensive forcefield around a space station big enough to be mistaken for a celestial body, in orbit.  *Where there is energy, the potential for catastrophic release of that energy exists,* period.  From a vase on a shelf to a battery to a reactor, things can go wrong, and the more energy they have, the bigger the mess they make when it happens.

Comment: This is why nuclear power plants can't go boom: they use low-enriched fuel, *deliberately keeping the amount of energy down* so that if there's a catastrophic event, you get a meltdown and not a mushroom cloud.  But when the power requirements are as high as this would have required, the catastrophic release would *necessarily* have been correspondingly higher.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - it is ironic that the quote at the top of the TV Tropes page for "Single Biome Planet" makes reference to the ice planet Hoth.  Of all the single biome planets in Star Wars, Hoth is the one that makes the most sense.  There are ice planets (or at least moons) in our own solar system.  There are no forest moons or desert planets, on the other hand.  Hoth is plausible;  Tatooine and Endor are not.

Comment: @MasonWheeler your assuming that these people who are 100's of thousands of years ahead of us in tech, have created power sources that, when they explode, blow massively, we can assume that the power source their using is similar to the one the rebels have on Hoth, and most likely similar to ones that would be on planets like coruscant. its not practical to have a power source that blows up half your damn city... If we can create massive amounts of power safely, i assume these highly advanced people can produce even more power, far more safely.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The clearest answer I can see has to do with the type of forest we're talking about.  The Endor scenes were filmed in California's Redwood National Park, which, as I understand it, is technically a [rainforest](http://www.gorp.com/parks-guide/travel-ta-redwood-national-park-ecotourism-crescent-city-hiking-sidwcmdev_055460.html).  Redwood forests like this one tend to be extremely damp and receive a lot of rain.  If you've ever seen a survival show set in the redwood forests (I believe "Dual Survival" has done an episode there), you know how much trouble the survivalists have in trying to start a campfire.  Everything in the forest is soaking wet most of the time.

And redwoods are especially resistant to forest fires:  the bark is thick and tough, and the foliage is so far above the ground that a fire on the forest floor can't reach high enough to get the branches and leaves burning.  Basically, the outer layer of bark gets scorched, but the tree itself doesn't catch fire, and the blaze just consumes the undergrowth and dead wood laying on the ground, leaving the trees largely unharmed, and even benefitting the trees by fertilizing the soil and making more room for new trees to grow.

I don't think that George Lucas expects us to believe that the trees on Endor are the same species we have on earth, but they are obviously quite similar to redwoods (and again, the trees we are seeing on our screens are in fact redwoods).  So the same rules that govern our redwood forests probably apply to Endor's forests as well.

Obviously, our redwoods don't have to deal with plasma bolts and blaster fire, but we could argue that the extreme heat produced by a blaster bolt dissipates so quickly that it doesn't have enough time to start a serious blaze.  It might not even be able to penetrate the thick layer of bark on the outside of the tree.

Considering how wet redwood forests are, it is actually kind of surprising that the Ewoks are able to have fires and torches at all.  I can only assume that they keep their firewood covered up so it can dry out before they need to use it.

And we could actually ask the same question about all sorts of substances that we see being hit by blaster fire.  Why don't people's clothes catch fire when they are shot?  Why doesn't *anything* catch fire when it is shot?